# How to compare dates in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, datetime, date, time, intervals

I have table (named `tasks`) with column `created_at` that, basically, contains UNIX time-stamp.

I need to select only those results that are created in specified time-interval.

Intervals are `today`, `tomorrow`, `this week` and `this month`.

I think that if I convert time-stamp to `YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS` format, MySQL can handle it.

Also, I think that I need to use `BETWEEN` there as well.

So, I pass time-stamp to query and compare (check?) that it's in the specified interval with time-stamp that is stored in the database. To convert, I need to use `FROM_UNIXTIME`, right?

How to specify those intervals? Thanks in an advice!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to convert UNIX_TIMESTAMP.

Query

```
SELECT * FROM tasks
WHERE created_at BETWEEN UNIX_TIMESTAMP(DATE_SUB(now(),INTERVAL 1 DAY)) 
                     AND UNIX_TIMESTAMP(now())
```

You can alter the interval for week, month etc by doing:

```
INTERVAL 1 WEEK
INTERVAL 1 MONTH
INTERVAL 1 YEAR
```

MySQL will automatically take the length of months and leap years etc into account.

In the above query MySQL will be able to use an index, speeding things up a lot.
Make sure **not** to use a function on your column, because in that case MySQL cannot use an index on that field, causing major slowness.

**Coding horror, very slow**

```
SELECT * FROM tasks 
WHERE FROM_UNIXTIME(created_at) BETWEEN DATE_SUB(now(),INTERVAL 1 DAY) 
                                    AND now()
```

See: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-add

Comment: No problem, just simple typo :)

Comment: Thanks, Johan. What about this month, for example? How much I need to put as the interval? 30?

Comment: `INTERVAL 7 DAY`, `INTERVAL 1 MONTH` (takes care of months with 31/29/28 days), `INTERVAL 1 YEAR` (takes care of leap years), all will work.

Answer (score 2):

I guess created_at is defined as INT and you store timestamps in it. Then the best way for, say, today, would be:

`created_at BETWEEN UNIX_TIMESTAMP(CURDATE()) AND UNIX_TIMESTAMP(CURDATE() + INTERVAL 1 DAY)`

Note the below will also work:

`FROM_UNIXTIME(created_at) BETWEEN CURDATE() AND (CURDATE() + INTERVAL 1 DAY)`

, but you'll probably have no chances to make MySQL use column indexes. For week/month you'll need a more complex logic with WEEK() and MONTH() built-in functions (to get the timestamp of the first second of the current week/month).